# H2 from version upgrade 1.3.176 - 2.2.224 Exception: Cannot find h2db client jar file, h2 jdbc driver will not be available by default

Tags: spring-boot, maven, h2

[technical debt] I needed H2 version upgrade to address security vulnerabilities in version 1.3.176 (Remote Code Execution (RCE) via H2 Console)
To version latest version 2.2.224 (i.e currently on Java 17)

Paraya - > 5.2022.5
JDK -> 17
Maven 3.6.3

Added +

```
`<dependency>
 <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
 <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.224</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>`
```

Removed -

```
`<dependency>
 <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
 <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.176</version>
 </dependency>`
```

Now my tests using H2 in memory DB are failing due to exception:

```
`com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findH2Client INFO: Cannot find h2db        client jar file, h2 jdbc driver will not be available by default (h2 version 2.2.224)
```

`

Could it be an issue caused by my eclipseLink version: 2.7.11 ?

```
`javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence   Services - 2.7.11.payara-p1): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal   Exception: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException
```

`

H2 community to please advise?